# Explanation of the error I get to compile the react-native code

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run a code in react-native after downloading it from the mail I got but I get the error as in the picture below. How to solve the error.
[image]

Just I wanna know is how to solve the error as it will run.

Comment: Have you installed dependencies first with `npm install`?

Comment: if you installed dependencies, try `npx react-native run-ios`